# Can someone give me an example of "pure pointer notation" to an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, notation

I'm looking for an example of 'pure pointer notation' in C. I have an assignment to convert a program to pure pointer notation and it uses a lot of arrays. Also, can you give an example of what would not constitute as pure pointer notation?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pure pointer notation basically just means using pointer arithmetic to address the elements of the array, rather than the `[...]` array index operator.

For example:

```
 someArray[10] = newValue;
```

is the same as

```
 *(someArray + 10) = newValue;
```

Comment: To be more precise, `x[y]` is defined as `*(x + y)`. That's why `x[y]` is equivalent to `y[x]`.

Comment: Great. This was exactly what I was looking for. I thought it was that but wasn't 100% sure. Thank you.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Indeed.  Constructions like `10[someArray]` tend to be a little more difficult to read, though.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The name of an array can be used as a pointer to the array's first element.  So `myArray` is equivalent to `&myArray[0]`, and `*myArray` is equivalent to `myArray[0]`.  You can then reach other indices of `myArray` with pointer arithmetic, so for instance `myArray[1]` is equivalent to `*(myArray + 1)`.